# Can I use submit handler even when I'm not validating my form using validate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form which I'm validating using normal if else conditions instead of rules. Can I still use submit handler on this. If yes, where do I place the submit handler.

I want to use submit handler because i want to implement a confirmation pop up on the click of sumbit button in the form

Comment: Of course. While submit handlers can be used for validation, they're not restricted to that. You create the submit handler the normal way, with `$("#formid").submit(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp for different ways to catch/handle onsubmit event.